# onClick attribute in XML linking to method in Activity class

Tags: android, android-layout, onclick

There are quite a few questions about this subject, but could not find any with the specific problem I have...

In my layout.xml, I use the `android:onClick` tag for a Button to call the right `onClickListener`. I get the error :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method handle_cancel(View) in the activity class com.matthieu.HelloWorldApplication for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button with id 'button_cancel'
```

I have that method implemented in the Activity, but it is looking for it in the class that extends `Application`... I don't understand why. The View and all that is setup only in the Activity.

If anyone needs, here is the declaration of that method (in my activity, NOT in HelloWorldApplication):

```
public void handle_cancel(View v) {
    // do something useful here
}
```

**Edit** (from adamp request)... and probably answering my own question :

Here is part of the code where that layout is used...

```
public class AddVocabularyActivity extends Activity
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.top); // that layout contains an empty LinearLayout id/main_content
    }

    private some_other_function() {
        LinearLayout main_content = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_content);
        main_content.removeAllViews();
        View.inflate(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.hello, main_content); // layout.hello is the one containing the button
    }

    // some other stuff
}
```

While copy/paste this code, I am guessing the problem is that I used `getApplicationContext` to inflate the View with that `Button`...

Comment: Can you post the code where you use that layout?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in my edit, changing the `getApplicationContext()` with the Activity context fixes it...

Comment: exactly. I inflated XML and it doesn't work with clicks. Changed getApplicationContext to this and it works!

Answer (score 0):

The convention works like this:
In the layout xml file, you give this attribute:
android:onClick:"methodname"

Then, inside a class, you define a method like this:

public void methodname(View v){
//your method code
}

Any other way of doing this is not documented. If you need parameters, just call another method inside that method.

Comment: I was doing all this correctly. The problem is in what class you should define that method. Especially when you use that layout by using a view inflater.

Comment: The problem is that this is just a helper, what you need to do if this doesn't fit, is just the usual Button button = (Button) findViewByID(R.id.yourbutton); And then the listener, etc.