# Android onClick method is not invoked

Tags: android, xml, button, onclick

I add the onclick method to my button in the `fragment2.xml`

```
   <Button
        android:id="@+id/getTextButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Kliknij do fragment 1"
        android:onClick="onClick" />
```

Then defined this method in Fragment2.java

```
public void onClick(View view){}
```

But when I click on it the app crashes? What is wrong full 
XML and java file below

```
package com.example.fragments;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


public class Fragment2 extends Fragment {


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstance){
        Log.d("Fragment 2", "metoda");
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment2, container, false);
    }

    public void onClick(View view){}

}
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#FFFF00" >

    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Fragment 2"
        android:textColor="#0000FF"
        android:textSize="25sp"/> <!-- moze byc px dp sp -->

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/getTextButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Kliknij do fragment 1"
        android:onClick="onClick" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: how do you know that is not invoked?

Comment: That's only effective on `Activity`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The onClick function that will be called with be in the context of the layout inflater.

Try to put the onClick function in your Activity rather than your Fragment and it should work.

I had a [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6590988/onclick-attribute-in-xml-linking-to-method-in-activity-class) before.

Answer (score 0):

for some unknown reason i had a similar issue, my onClick that is declared in XML worked on some devices and didnt work on some others

i assigned an

```
OnClickListener
```

to the same view, and in this listener i invoked the

```
activity.onClick(view)
```

manually, it worked

a SILLY bug in android !!!!

Answer (score 0):

On my case, having the "onClick" function on the activity, I just had to clean the project... 
The on onClick call from xml worked after that.