# My method on onClick event method does not do anything

Tags: java, android, onclick

I am working on an android project

1. Create a method on `MainActivity` as below:

   ```
   public void diagnose(View View) {

       System.out.println("%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% INSIDE DIAGNOSE %%%%%%%%%%%%%%");

       String PTCondition = " ";

       int row, col, count, percentageOfLikelihood, maxPercent = 0;

       //To store the name of each condition and its percentage of likelihood
       String[][] percentPerCondition = new String[8][];

       percentPerCondition[0][0] = "Rotator Cuff Strain";
       percentPerCondition[1][0] = "Coracoid Impingement";
       percentPerCondition[2][0] = "Supraspinatus Impingement";
       percentPerCondition[3][0] = "Bicipital Tendonitis";
       percentPerCondition[4][0] = "Glenohumeral Dislcation";
       percentPerCondition[5][0] = "Clavicular Fracture";
       percentPerCondition[6][0] = "Labral Tear";
       percentPerCondition[7][0] = "SubAcromial Bursitis";

       //Store binary sequence of Special Tests that correspond to the conditions above
       int[][] STValuesPercondition = new int[][] {
           {
               1, 0, 1, 0, 1
           }, {
               0, 1, 0, 1, 1
           }, {
               0, 1, 1, 0, 0
           }, {
               1, 1, 0, 0, 1
           }, {
               0, 0, 1, 1, 1
           }, {
               1, 1, 0, 1, 0
           }, {
               1, 0, 1, 1, 0
           }, {
               0, 1, 1, 1, 0
           }
       };

       //Compare the binary sequence in PTFindings to all conditions
       for (row = 0; row < STValuesPercondition.length; row++) {
           count = 0;
           for (col = 0; col < STValuesPercondition.length; col++) {
               if (STValuesPercondition[row][col] == PTFindings[row]) count++;
           }

           //Calculate percentage of likelihood
           percentageOfLikelihood = (count / 5) * 100;
           if (percentageOfLikelihood > maxPercent) {
               maxPercent = percentageOfLikelihood;
               PTCondition = percentPerCondition[row][0];
           }

           System.out.println("&&&&&&& Inside diagnosis: " + PTCondition);
           //Store percentage as a String in the percentPerCondition 2D array; may need it later
           percentPerCondition[row][1] = Integer.toString(percentageOfLikelihood);
       }

       //Point to the TextView where data to be displayed - in layout file (displaydx)
       DxTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dx1);

       //Populate the textView with the data from
       DxTextView.setText(PTCondition);

       //Display the PTCondition on the activity
       String passPTCondition = "";

       Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DisplayDxActivity.class);
       i.putExtra(passPTCondition, PTCondition);
       startActivity(i);

   } //public void diagnose(View View)
   ```
2. Here is my layout file; it seems like the method ( diagnose(View View) ) does not get called. My diagnose() method is defined in onCreate()
   Nothing happens when I click on diagnose? !!!!

   ```
   <Button
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="Generate Possible Diagnoses"
       android:id="@+id/SubmitButton"
       android:textColor="#ffff6949"
       android:background="#ffffffff"
       android:textStyle="bold"
       android:onClick="diagnose" />

   <TextView
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
       android:id="@+id/dx1"
       android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
   ```

Comment: try `public void diagnose(View view)`, with the lower case view.

Comment: Tried it and still does not work

Comment: How about `public void diagnose(View v)`?

Comment: Still does not work; it does not execute this line:  System.out.println("%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% INSIDE DIAGNOSE %%%%%%%%%%%%%%");    I am assuming it does not even call diagnose()

Comment: Does this answer help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15512965/android-onclick-method-is-not-invoked

Comment: where do you print the first line???

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to be right apart from the code convention mistake in the view parameter name.

Ensure you inflate your layout in your `onCreate` method and your `diagnose` method will be called.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.your_main_layout);
    // Where your_main_layout is the one who has the android:onClick="diagnose"
    // Rest of the code...
}
```

Just in case, say that `android:onClick` was introduced in API level 4 onwards so ensure your API target fulfills that.

EDIT:

As another test you could add the `View.OnClickListener` listener to your activity and get all onClick events by View id's adding this method to your MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.your_main_layout);
      findViewById(R.id.SubmitButton).setOnClickListener(this);
  }
  ....
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.SubmitButton:
                diagnose(v);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

@Mike as @Coeus well has detected too, move the `diagnose` method out of `onCreate` and make it a MainActivity class method. Otherwise when Android looks for the `diagnose` method found in the Layout using reflection, it won't find anything.

Comment: No no, the rest of the code of the `onCreate`, the rest of the code is fine.

Comment: You don't have to add any extra code lines in the `onCreate` method apart from the two I wrote above. Ensure you are referencing your XML layout file  with `setContentView` and your method should be fired when clicked.

Comment: I already have this:  setContentView(R.layout.shoulder_layout) in onCreate; which points to the layout I am using

Comment: Did you debug your app? Please do it and notify when the app crash

Comment: @Coeus No, I wrote my code right here. I forgot to add the listener, my code would never crash though.

Comment: After reading and reading and reading, I though that the problem can be this : "My diagnose() method is defined in onCreate()" as Mike says

Comment: That's it! I didn't read that, why would someone declare that method inside `onCreate`?

Comment: I dont know! But he/she did it!